# In Oracle PL/SQL, How do I check if a JSON object contains an element of a specific key

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure as shown below. It accepts a JSON object as an input. One of the elements in this object type is an array with the key `samplekey`. In some cases, the JSON object `p_object` does not contain the `samplekey` array. In those instances, the procedure encounters a runtime exception. What is the best way to handle this scenario in PL/SQL? Should I have to check for the existence of an element with key `samplekey` in the object `p_object` first? If yes, how do I do this? Is there a better way to handle such scenarios?

```
procedure(p_object in json_object_t)
as

lja json_array_t;

begin

lja   := p_object.get_array('samplekey');

end;
```

Comment: It depends. What do you want the procedure to do when that error is found? If you want it ignored (and do something entirely different, that doesn't use that array), then you can check for existence in an `if` statement. Otherwise just handle the error in the error handling section of your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `HAS` function of `JSON_OBJECT_T`. This will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the JSON has the key you search for. Below is an example of how to use it.

```sql
DECLARE
    PROCEDURE test_json (p_object IN json_object_t)
    IS
    BEGIN
        IF p_object.has ('samplekey')
        THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('JSON has the key "samplekey"');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('JSON does NOT have the key "samplekey"');
        END IF;
    END;
BEGIN
    test_json (json_object_t ('{}'));
    test_json (json_object_t ('{"samplekey":123}'));
    test_json (json_object_t ('{"otherkey":"test"}'));
END;
/

--Output
JSON does NOT have the key "samplekey"
JSON has the key "samplekey"
JSON does NOT have the key "samplekey"
```